# ui-router-- having a route's URL share the same level as another state with $stateParams?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'd like to do something like this in my application, where the same level of the URL hits the either the `baz` state, that absolutely named, or the `biz` state that takes a parameter.

```
angular.module('foo')
.config(function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider
  .state('baz', {
    url: '/baz',
    templateUrl: '/templates/baz.html'
  })
  .state('biz', {
    url: '/:biz',
    templateUrl: '/templates/biz.html',
    resolve: {
      biz: function($stateParams){
        // resolve whatever $stateParams.biz should be
      }
    }
  })
})
```

However, what's happening is ui-router is *always* hitting the `biz` state, and interpreting "baz" as a parameter for that state. Is there an elegant way to let ui-router know that anything that hits "/baz" should resolve to the `baz` state?

I know I can use `$stateChangeStart` and do something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams){
  if (toParams.biz === "baz"){
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('baz')
  }
})
```

But this is far from elegant and seems like a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created [a plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rf7wO7Ed3gSWBZMstFzE?p=preview), which in fact shows, that the above *state* snippet is WORKING. Why, because these states are defined in the correct order:

```
.state('baz', {
    url: '/baz', // url '/baz' is registered first, will be find and used
    ...
})
.state('biz', {
    url: '/:biz', // '/baz' will never reach this, because is already handled
    ...
```

The way how we can make it broken, is to switch the state def:

```
.state('biz', {
    url: '/:biz', // '/baz' will be handled by this state
    ...
.state('baz', {
    url: '/baz', // url '/baz' never reach this state def...
    ...
})
```

Check the [broken link here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6bSNWTbL8OHHXGSNw5zr?p=preview)

Summary:

> state definition order is important. **The first state `url` match is used**

Comment: This is really weird. It's definitely working in the plunker you created, but it's not working in my app. Thanks for taking the time to look into this, I'll have to isolate more conditions and figure out what's really going on.

Comment: Figured it out. **It's because my first state that I was trying to hit is abstract**, and it looks like angular defers to non-abstract states regardless of order.

Comment: Great, that you make it! Enjoy ui-router :)