# Why nested state's content gets appended to root state html?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

**root html:**

```
<html> stuff <div ui-view></div> stuff </html>
```

**partial template**

```
<div class="article-view">
{{date_published}}
</div>
```

When I navigate using `$state.go('root.' + entryStateUrl);` the url changes but new state's content (template) is appended right after root's state content. I need to show template on new clean page. How to do it?

Maybe similar to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808672/ui-router-having-a-routes-url-share-the-same-level-as-another-state-with-sta).

**Edit**
I generated and attached states like this:

```
$stateProviderRef.state('root.' + generatedStateName,
                        { url: 'root/' + generatedStateName,
                            templateUrl : 'partials/article-view.html', 
                                controller:   function($scope){
                                    $scope.date_published = data.date_published;

                            }
                        });
```

**UPDATE**

When I changed it like this it stopped working:

```
$stateProviderRef.state(generatedStateName,
                            { url: generatedStateName,
                                templateUrl : 'partials/article-view.html', 
                                    controller:   function($scope){
                                        $scope.date_published = data.date_published;

                                }
                            });
```

Comment: So are you saying you don't want a template view? You want a totally separate html page?

Comment: div tags are not self closing. `<div ui-view></div>`

Comment: @mindparse, yes, I need to navigate user to new page within `ui-router` bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting to a new page means you won't be able to bind to the controller used from the origin page, since the redirected page won't have any attachment to your js code.

Comment: I mean redirect is not to reload page but navigate to template and display accordingly . Now it is just being appended to root state. I don't want than mess. Is the a way to fix it?